# Let $f \in AC[0,1],f(0)=0 $. Show that $\int_0^1 \lvert f(x)f'(x)\rvert\,dx \leq \int_0^1\lvert f'(x)\rvert^2 \, dx$

Tags: real-analysis

I tried to prove this problem by this way but stuck:

Let $x_0 = 0\lt x_1 \lt x_2<\cdots< x_n=1$

\begin{align}
& \int_0^1\left| f(x)f'(x)\right|\,dx = \int_0^1\left| f(x)\frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)}{h}\right|\,d \\[10pt]
= {} & \int_0^1 \left| \frac {f(x)f(x_0+h)}{h} \right| \, dx - \int_0^1\left| \frac{f(x)f(x_0)}{h}\right| \,dx \\[10pt]
= {} & \int_0^1\left| \frac{f(x)f(h)}{h}\right| - \left| \frac{f(h)}{h}\right|\,dx \int_0^1\left| f(x)\right| \,dx
\end{align}

and

$$\int_0^1\left| f'(x)\right|^2\,dx = \int_0^1\left| \frac{f(x_0+h-f(x_0)}{h} \right|^2 \,dx = \int_0^1\left| \frac{f(h)}{h}\right|^2\,dx = \left| \frac{f(h)}{h} \right|^2$$

I tried to simplify left and right hand side, but there is no obvious way to prove. Or maybe I am on the worng direction?

Comment: Most of those manipulations are incorrect. For example $f'(x) = [f(x_0 + h) - f(x_0)]/h$ makes no sense. What is $x_0$, and you need a limit here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have

$$|f(x)| = \left|\int_0^x f'(t) \, dt \right| \leqslant \int_0^x |f'(t)| \, dt.$$

Define

$$F(x) = \int_0^x |f'(t)| \, dt. $$

Then $F(0) = 0$, $F'(x) = |f'(x)|$ and

$$\int_0^1 |f(x)f'(x)| \, dx \leqslant \int_0^1F(x)F'(x) \, dx = \int_0^1\frac{1}{2}(F^2)' \, dx =\frac{1}{2}F^2(1).$$

By the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality,

$$\frac{1}{2}F^2(1) = \frac{1}{2} \left(\int_0^1|f'(x)| \, dx \right)^2 \leqslant \frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 |f'(x)|^2 \, dx.$$

Therefore,

$$\int_0^1 |f(x)f'(x)| \, dx \leqslant \frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 |f'(x)|^2 \, dx < \int_0^1 |f'(x)|^2 \, dx $$

Comment: May I ask why $\int_0^1F(x)F'(x)dx =\frac{1}{2}F^2(1)$?

Comment: @Wade: Because $F(x)F' (x)= \frac{1}{2} \frac{d}{dx}F^2(x)$ and $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{2} \frac{d}{dx}F^2(x) \, dx = \frac{1}{2}F^2(1) - \frac{1}{2}F^2(0) =  \frac{1}{2}F^2(1)$. Recall that $F(0) = 0.$

Comment: Yes, you are right!

Comment: @Wade: You're welcome.