# Prove that $\int_0^a |f(x)|^2|f'(x)|dx \le \frac{a^2}{3}\int_0^a |f'(x)|^3dx$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, inequality, integral-inequality

> If $f \in C^1([0,a])$ and $f(0) = 0$, prove that
> $$\int_0^a |f(x)|^2|f'(x)|dx \le \frac{a^2}{3}\int_0^a |f'(x)|^3dx$$
> when does the equality hold?

**My attempt:** Since $f(0) = 0$, we have $$f(x) = \int_0^x f'(t)dt$$
Plugging it into the LHS of the inequality the LHS becomes
$$\int_0^a |f(x)|^2|f'(x)|dx  = \int_0^a \left|\int_0^x f'(t)dt \right|^2 f'(x)dx$$
Due to the [Cauchy-Bunyakovskiy inequality](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Cauchy-Bunyakovsky-Schwarz_Inequality/Definite_Integrals) for $1$ and $f'(t)$, we have
$$\begin{align}
\int_0^a \left|\int_0^x f'(t)dt \right|^2 f'(x)dx 
&\le \int_0^a\left(\int_0^x 1^2 dt\right)\left(\int_0^x [f'(t)]^2dt \right)f'(x)dx \\
&= \int_0^a \int_0^x xf'(x)[f'(t)]^2dt dx \\
&= \int_0^x [f'(t)]^2dt\int_0^axf'(x)dx \\ 
&= \left(xf(x)|_0^a - \int_0^a f(x)dx \right)\int_0^x [f'(t)]^2dt \\
&= af(a)\int_0^x [f'(t)]^2dt - \int_0^a f(x)dx \int_0^x [f'(t)]^2dt
\end{align}$$
I got stuck here. I cannot figure out the best way to observe the result.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can proceed similarly as in [Let $f \in AC[0,1],f(0)=0 $. Show that $\int_0^1 \lvert f(x)f'(x)\rvert\,dx \leq \int_0^1\lvert f'(x)\rvert^2 \, dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2033935/let-f-in-ac0-1-f0-0-show-that-int-01-lvert-fxfx-rvert-dx-leq):

We have
$$
|f(x)| = \left| \int_0^1 f'(t) \, dt \right| \le \int_0^x |f'(t)| \, dt =: F(x) \, ,
$$
with equality for all $x$ if and only if $f'$ has constant sign on $[0, a]$.

Then $F'(x) = |f'(x)|$ and
$$
\int_0^a |f(x)|^2|f'(x)|dx  \le \int_0^a F(x)^2 F'(x) \, dx = \frac 13 F(a)^3 \, .
$$

Then $F(a)$ can be estimated Hölder's inequality (with $p=3/2$ and $q=3$), this gives
$$
 F(a) = \int_0^a 1 \cdot |f'(x)|\, dx \le a^{2/3} \cdot
\left( \int_0^a |f'(x)|^3 \, dt \right)^{1/3} \, ,
$$
with equality if and only if $|f'|$ is constant on $[0, a]$.

Combining these estimates gives the desired result.

*Remark:* In the same way one can prove that
$$
\int_0^a |f(x)|^p|f'(x)| \, dx \le \frac{a^p}{p+1}\int_0^a |f'(x)|^{p+1} \, dx
$$
for any $p \ge 1$.